# How do I tell Ansible to include localhost on the task?

Tags: ansible

I have this task:

```yaml
- name: Install OpenJDK
  become: true
  apt:
    name: openjdk-8-jre-headless
    cache_valid_time: 60
    state: latest
```

I want to run it in all hosts, including localhost. How can I tell Ansible to include localhost in the hosts for just one play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just add `localhost` to the [pattern](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) of targeted hosts in your play. Note that, unless your re-define it in your inventory, [`localhost` is implicit](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html) and does not match the `all` special group.

The global idea

```yaml
---
- name: This play will target all hosts in inventory
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: I'm a dummy task

- name: This play will target all inventory hosts AND implicit localhost
  hosts: all:localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Yet an other dummy task
```